# The reverse proxy Setting in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy server(IIS 10.0 ARR) which rewrite to application server with self-signed certification(IIS　10.0).
When Rewrited to the application server thorough the reverse proxy server, 502 server error is returned.
I guess it's because of a self-signed certification.
In the case of Apache, SSLProxyVerify server property exists...

How can I ignore self-signed certification??
I don't like to make the reverse proxy server verify the application server's certification.

Any ideas?